# Is there a more efficient way to import MASS data into SQL database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to import around 5000 rows of data in my SQL database I am using mysqli_prepare and binding parameters and executing per row currently but Im sure there must be a better way. I am just struggling to find good information on this subject.

Below is my current code (its messy I know!)

```
<?php


ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once( "./_inc/glob.php" );
global $params;
$con = mysqli_connect( $params['db']['hostname'], $params['db']['username'], $params['db']['password'] );
mysqli_select_db( $con, $params['db']['database'] );
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
putenv( "TZ=Europe/London" );
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$company = $_GET["company"];
$now = time();
if (!$con) die(mysqli_connect_error());  // else show an error

function checkSQLTableExists($name, $con){
    $table_list = array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($con->query('SHOW TABLES')),0);
    $ExistingTable = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i <count($table_list);$i++){
            if ($table_list[$i] == $name) {
            $ExistingTable = true;
        }  
    }
    if (!$ExistingTable){// if table does not exist Create it.....
        if (!mysqli_query($con,"CREATE TABLE `pricedata`.`".$name."` ( `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `close_date` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , `1. open` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\"0\"' , `2. high` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\"0\"' , `3. low` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\"0\"' , `4. close` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\"0\"' , `5. adjusted close` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\"0\"' , `6. volume` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\"0\"' , `7. dividend amount` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\"0\"' , `8. split coefficient` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\"0\"' , PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE (`close_date`)) ENGINE = innodb;"))$ExistingTable = true;
        else $ExistingTable = false;  // set return to false if Table is no created.
    $ExistingTable = true;
    }
    return $ExistingTable;
}

// Initialize a file URL to the variable 
$url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/'.$company.'?period1=-1262304000&period2='.$now.'&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'; 
  
// Use basename() function to return the base name of file  
$file_name = str_split(basename($url),4)[0].".csv"; 
$handle = null;
$dir = "./Price_data/";

$row = 0; // set the row for skipping first row later.
if(file_put_contents($dir.$file_name,file_get_contents($url))) { //Save CSV to file and if successful continue
    if (($handle = fopen($dir.$file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        if (checkSQLTableExists("Daily_".$company, $con)){ //Check Database table exists/If not it will create one and return true if successful.
        $data = array();
        $query = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO `Daily_".$company."` (`id`,`close_date`,`1. open`, `2. high`, `3. low`, `4. close`, `5. adjusted close`, `6. volume`, `7. dividend amount`, `8. split coefficient`) VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                if ($row > 0){ //We dont want the first row.
                    
                    $date = $data[0];
                    $open = $data[1];
                    $high = $data[2];
                    $low = $data[3];
                    $close = $data[4];
                    $adjClose = $data[5];
                    $volume = $data[6];
                    $divAmount = 0;
                    $split = 0;

                    $query->bind_param('sdddddddd',$date,$open,$high,$low,$close,$adjClose,$volume,$divAmount,$split);
                    $query->execute();

                    //if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Daily_".$company."
                    //(`id`, `close_date`, `1. open`, `2. high`, `3. low`, `4. close`, `5. adjusted close`, `6. volume`, `7. dividend amount`, `8. split coefficient`)
                    //VALUES (NULL,'$date','$open', '$high','$low','$close','$adjClose','$volume',0,0)"))$test="true";
                    
                }
                $row++; // increase row.
            }
        }else echo"ERROR: Table does not exist and could not be created";
    }else echo"ERROR: CSV File Could not be created";
}else echo "ERROR:"; 
 
 


?>
```

thanks for taking the time to read this, Any information I can gleam from this will be helpful.

Comment: If the data is in a CSV file you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load it.

Comment: first of all you could create just one sql string and execute it at the end of the loop

Comment: @barmar would this be effected by the csv headers though? Also the data in the CSV is only partial to what what I would want to be adding to the SQL thus the 0 variables in the code. Giacomo M- how would I go about doing that? Is there a way to explode an array similar to how I can currently doing it?  Thanks to both of you for your input!

Comment: No, it can't get the column names from the headers, you have to tell it specifically how the CSV fields correspond to table columns. You can use the `SET` clause to specify the values for columns that aren't in the CSV. Read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I shall read up on this now.